# Compile generate 0 byte files on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I am working on a project that is a little bit hard for me because I don't have an extensive knowledge of Mac OS.

I have a project that works on Windows and I have to compile it on Mac OS, with Qt.

The problem is when I build the project, it generates me only empty files : .dylib .o .cpp and .h

am I missing something like a special command in the .pro file ?

Here is one .pro (others are nearly identical) :

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2016-04-18T21:12:51
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += widgets

TARGET = MdDimension
TEMPLATE = lib

DEFINES += MDDIMENSION_LIBRARY \
_TOOLKIT_IN_DLL_ \

INCLUDEPATH += ../MdCore \
        ../MdWidgets \
        ../include \
        ../include/teigha \
        ../include/Extensions/ExServices \
        ./GUI \

release {
DESTDIR = ../release
}

debug {
DESTDIR = ../debug
}

SOURCES += mddimensionmodule.cpp \
    widgets/mddimstylecombo.cpp \
    GUI/mddimstyletoolbar.cpp

HEADERS += mddimensionmodule.h\
    widgets/mddimstylecombo.h \
    GUI/mddimstyletoolbar.h \
    mddimensiondefs.h


win32{
    CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
        LIBS += -L$$PWD/../build/debug -lMdCore \
                -L$$PWD/../build/debug -lMdWidgets \
                -L$$PWD/../build/debug -lMdModels \

        # Librairies ODA
        LIBS += -L$$PWD/../lib/win32/debug -lTD_Db \
         -L$$PWD/../lib/win32/debug -lTD_Root \
         -L$$PWD/../lib/win32/debug -lTD_Alloc \
         -L$$PWD/../lib/win32/debug -lTD_DbRoot \
        -ladvapi32

        DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../lib/win32/debug
    }
    CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
        LIBS += -L$$PWD/../build/release -lMdCore \
                -L$$PWD/../build/release -lMdWidgets \
                -L$$PWD/../build/release -lMdModels \

        # Librairies ODA
        LIBS += -L$$PWD/../lib/win32/release -lTD_Db \
         -L$$PWD/../lib/win32/release -lTD_Root \
         -L$$PWD/../lib/win32/release -lTD_Alloc \
         -L$$PWD/../lib/win32/release/ -lTD_DbRoot \
        -ladvapi32

        DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../lib/win32/release
    }
}


unix{
    CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
        LIBS += -L$$PWD/../build/debug -lMdCore \
                -L$$PWD/../build/debug -lMdWidgets \
                -L$$PWD/../build/debug -lMdModels \

        # Librairies ODA
        LIBS += -L$$PWD/../lib/unix/debug -lTD_Db \
         -L$$PWD/../lib/unix/debug -lTD_Root \
         -L$$PWD/../lib/unix/debug -lTD_Alloc \
         -L$$PWD/../lib/unix/debug/ -lTD_DbRoot \

        DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../lib/unix/debug
    }
    CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
        LIBS += -L$$PWD/../build/release -lMdCore \
                -L$$PWD/../build/release -lMdWidgets \
                -L$$PWD/../build/release -lMdModels \

        # Librairies ODA
        LIBS += -L$$PWD/../lib/unix/release -lTD_Db \
         -L$$PWD/../lib/unix/release -lTD_Root \
         -L$$PWD/../lib/unix/release -lTD_Alloc \
         -L$$PWD/../lib/unix/release -lTD_DbRoot \

        DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../lib/unix/release
    }
}

unix {
    target.path = /usr/lib
    INSTALLS += target
}



TARGET_EXT = _4.02_14.mrx

RESOURCES += \
    mddimension.qrc
```

I don't have any error or warning when I build a library.

So if anyone have a clue or an explanation to the problem, I will be interested :)

Thank you !

Comment: There isn't nearly enough information in this question to figure out what goes wrong for you :( It's supposed to work. Try and remove the `DESTDIR`  lines: they don't belong in a `.pro` file anyway, since a `.pro` file shouldn't be in control of the build destination. The build is controlled solely by where you run `qmake`. You can (and should!) have multiple builds of your application existing side-by-side.

Comment: Thanks for your response, here is more information : I'm using Qt 5.7, with QtCreator 4.0.2. I have one build per library (10 in total) + on build for the main project.
And now I've got 4 warnings : 

`-------------- /build/Makefile:1959: avertissement : overriding commands for target 'install_target' 

/build/Makefile:1944: avertissement : ignoring old commands for target ---------------
/build/Makefile:1959: avertissement : overriding commands for target 'uninstall_target'

/build/Makefile:1944: avertissement : ignoring old commands for target 'uninstall_target'`

Comment: [Here is the link](https://forum.qt.io/topic/69171/compile-generate-0-byte-files-on-os-x/24) to the solution from the same user in officials Qt forums, just for everyone information.